# Appending specific text to output data to make url

Tags: python

Need to append (add) specific text to all output lines and ultimately make a url . More explanation after code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('div', class_="mw-category")

heroes_names = []

savefile = open('file.txt', 'w')

for link in link:
    link = link.text
    # print(link)
    heroes = link.split("\n")
    # print(heroes)
    for i in range(1,len(heroes)):
        # print(heroes)
        heroname = heroes[i].split("/")[0]
        print(heroname)
        heroes_names.append(heroname)
        savefile.write(heroname + "\n")

# for hero_name in heroes_names:
#     print(hero_name)
savefile.close()
```

required output:

- Abaddon/counters
- Alchemist/counters
- and so on

final requirement :

- https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters
- https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Alchemist/Counters
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

So you already have all your hero names in heroes_names as strings right ? Then you can create the urls like this:

```
url_list = []
for hero_name in heroes_names:
    print(hero_name + "/counters") # Prints out HERO/counters
    url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com/%s/Counters" % hero_name
    url_list.append(url)
```

url_list then contains all urls for heroes in your heroes_names list.